# `xset m` value keeps reverting during PC use

Tags: 14.04, xorg, mouse, input-devices, mouse-pointer

I'm using

```
xset m 0 0
```

To disable mouse acceleration. I also have it in a startup script as such:

*~/bin/mouseaccdisable*

```
#!/bin/bash

xset m 0 0
```

(I also have that command in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.)

I've been having trouble making it *stick*. The command works but it randomly switches back to some default `xset m` setting (sometimes within minutes, sometimes in around 30 minutes). Because of that I have got that `mouseaccdisable` script called with a `* * * * *` crontab entry to keep it that way.

1. How can I debug this? I would like to see when and why this is happening.
2. If anyone has a direct solution or any knowledge as to why this might be happening, all info would be great.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) on a fairly recent PC. My mouse is a Logitech G502, but this problem occured earlier with a Logitech G500 mouse too. The G502 is a new mouse and the G500 was a 3-4 year old mouse.

I have not installed any drivers other than what Ubuntu offered during first installation. I use the PC for programming and web development so there should not be any *strange* software running either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a stupid mistake regarding this issue.

I noticed that the mouse acceleration was reverted each and every time I opened a new tmux split in my terminal. I figured I'd check through stuff that is loaded on all new terminal sessions and found a random `xset m 2/3 0` line inside my `.bashrc` file.

So the solution to this was to get rid of that line. I've been running for about an hour now with my sensitivity sticking correctly to `xset m 0`.

I feel like a real idiot right about now. :D